# java desktop application not running from executable jar file

Tags: java, mysql

I had created one application in java net beans with MySQL connectivity ,
its running well in net beans but when I created its executable jar file , it does not run form jar icon . How can I make it run from it.

Comment: you need to make a .bat file that executes your .jar file.

I'lll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

When You build a java project you get a .jar file as output which you can not execute.

To execute this file you will have to make some kind of launcher. This can be done easily with a .bat file on windows

For example I have a .jar file called game.jar

Make a text file write the following code, then save as .bat

```
java -jar game.jar
```

Make sure the .bat file is located in the same directory as the .jar file

Extra info:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html